# when i edited a deleted post, is it automatically shown to moderators?

Tags: support

i wanted to write here just "." (a dot), in the textarea, but i could not submit form.

then i have copied title, and i could not submit form.

then i have edited this way:

When i edited a deleted post, is it automatically shown to moderators by notification and/or in some undeletion queue?

and i could not submit form.

now i have added all this things not about my answer, but about another problem, so that this question can easily can be used as example for that problem.

then i also tried to delete all text from textarea, and expectedly, i could not submit form.

**my question is**: when i edited a deleted post, is it automatically shown to moderators?

Comment: [should not you decrease length limit for meta questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297698/should-not-you-decrease-length-limit-for-meta-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The only notification that editing a deleted post does is bumping that post in the active questions feed, just like any other edit. Users who have sufficient reputation (i.e. [2,000 reputation for beta sites](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) to see deleted posts can see these edits and, if it's a question, vote to undelete it. Trusted Users (i.e. [4,000 reputation for beta sites](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) can also vote to undelete answers. In both cases, undelete votes can only be cast if the post hadn't been deleted by a diamond moderator, in which case only diamond moderator can undelete it.

If a post needs community attention, the best way to get that is to make a specific post about it in [meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com) or bring it up in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=sitet&host=islam.stackexchange.com). If a post needs diamond moderator attention, flag it for moderator attention with an explanation of *why*.