# My answer about dancing is not undeleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

[Is there any verse in the Quran which states that dancing is haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36142/is-there-any-verse-in-the-quran-which-states-that-dancing-is-haram/40907#40907)

was deleted probably for not directly answering the question - not referencing ayats of quran, and maybe also for shortness and maybe also for lack of proof links.

I have edited it now and [flagged](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/when-i-edited-a-deleted-post-is-it-automatically-shown-to-moderators) it with message "will not you undelete this?", but I have not seen any reaction.

Comment: You are not patient enough do you know how much time and activity it needs to close a post etc.? at the moment your undelete request needs up to 17 votes to re-appear for <2500 rep users. If anybody was doing his duty when it comes to review queues everything would work faster on the site... but unfortunately not enough people are active!

Comment: Also: The answer is currently on a -4 score, which won't be erased by undeleting it.  It's likely some of those downvoters will not see the changes and retract their downvotes.  (Why not just post another answer with a clean slate? [I'm not sure if the software allows this.])

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones i can write new answer, even writing 2nd answer when 1st is not closed is possible

Comment: @Medi1Saif you mean that some 17 users with some moderator privileges should vote to undelete? btw i tried to press undelete but i see then "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted" - so who can undelete it? maybe only diamond moderators?

Comment: I see now it says it might need 18 and I've got the same message as you described... Then your only chance is to follow Rebecca's suggestion!

Comment: @Medi1Saif does it mean that 18 users can undelete it or 1 or 2 diamond moderator? then why diamond moderators still does not undelete it?